# adding two two-dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, matrix

i start with:

```
 typedef struct
{
    int rows, cols;
    int **element;
}Matrix;
```

and i create two matrices:

```
void matrixInit (Matrix *m, int r, int c )
{
    m->element = malloc(sizeof(int*)*r);
    for (int j=0;j<3;++j)
    {
        m->element[j] = malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
    }
    m->rows=r;
    m->cols=c;
 }
Matrix m1,m2,m3;
matrixInit(&m1,3,3);
    for (k=0; k<m1.cols*m1.rows; k++)
        {
            m1.element[k]=q;
            q++;
        }
```

then i do matrix 2 using copy function created

```
void matrixCopy (Matrix *m, Matrix *n )
{
    int r=n->rows,c=n->cols,k;
    for (k=0; k<r*c; k++)
    {
        m->element[k]=n->element[k];
    }
}

matrixInit(&m2, 3, 3);
matrixCopy(&m2, &m1);
```

and then i create a third to be the result of the addition

```
matrixInit(&m3, 3, 3);
```

then i do the addition. this is where my problem lies. I cannot seem to get this to work.

my code for the function is below:
(the prototype must stay the same)

```
Matrix* matrixAdd (Matrix *m, Matrix *n )
{
    int q;
    for (q=0; q<m->rows*m->cols; q++)
    {
        m->element[q]=*m->element[q]+*n->element[q];
    }
    return m;
}
m3=*matrixAdd(&m1, &m2);
```

Comment: Add the programming language, where you perform this implementation.

Comment: Is the addition function supposed to *allocate* a new matrix? Because your's currently modifies the first-parameter in-place, then returns its address. The result in your code usage is leaked memory from `m3`, and two-matrices (m3 and m1) that are pointing to **the same buffer**. In summary, *that isn't good*.

Comment: (a) The `for (int j=0; j<3; ++j)` loop should be `for (int j=0; j<r; ++j)` (`r` instead of `3`); (b) the function creates but does not initialize the matrix; the values in the cells is indeterminate. For pity's sake, please use spaces: the loop `for (q=0; q<m->rows*m->cols; q++)` is damned hard to read, compared with: `for (q = 0; q < m->rows * m->cols; q++)`.

Comment: Also, since `m3 == &m1` after the call, returning the matrix as a pointer is a little pointless.  Either you need to allocate a result matrix in the function or you don't need to return a pointer to the result. Since you can't change the prototype, you need to allocate the matrix in the addition function.

Answer (score 1):

`matrixAdd` function should be as follows: `*` on element will refer to first value only.

```
Matrix* matrixAdd (Matrix *m, Matrix *n )
{
    int q;
    int r;
    for(r = 0; r<m->rows; ++r)
       for (q=0; q<m->cols; q++)
       {
           m->element[r][q]=m->element[r][q]+n->element[r][q];
       }

    return m;
}
```

This will be more readable can be understood.

In your case,

```
   *m->element[q] = *m->element[q]+*n->element[q];
```

will lead you into problem as you have allocated r pointers to `int *` (therefore r continuous element) and at each pointer you have allocated c integers.

Therefore, if q is beyond r, behaviour is not defined.

Comment: `*m->element[q] = *m->element[q]+*n->element[q];` gets me "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x1)"

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. I edited the answer by stating the reason.

Comment: Is `q<m->rows*m->cols` correct? Looks like it should be `q<m->cols`

Comment: This is one of the times when `m->element[r][q] += n->element[r][q];` really helps; you don't have to look hard to see if two of the three expressions are the same.